# Crop a collection of lines using another collection of lines

Tags: python, algorithm, 2d, pseudocode

First of all, here is a quick graphical description of what I intend to do. I will use Python, but feel free to use pseudo code in your answers.

[image: Graphical description]

I have 2 collections of *2D* segments, stored as the following: `[ [start_point, end_point], [...] ]`.

For the first step, I have to detect each segment of the *blue* collection which is colliding with the *black* collection. For this I use LeMothe's line/line intersection algorithm.

Then comes my first problem: Having a segment **AB** which intersects with my line in **C**, I don't know how to determine using code if I have to trim my segment as **AC** or as **CB** , ie: I don't know which part of my segment I need to keep and which one I need to remove.

Then for the second step, I have really no ideas how to achieve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second step is trivial once you figure what to keep and what not, you just need to keep track of the segments you clipped and see where they were originally joined (e.g. assume that the segments are in order and form a connected line).
On the other hand, given that your black line is in fact a line and not a polygon, in your first step, choosing what is "outside" and what is "inside" seems completely arbitrary; is it possible to close that into a polygon? Otherwise, you may need to artificially create two polygons (one for each side of the line) and then do clipping inside those polygons. You could use something like the Cyrus and Beck line clipping algorithm (see this tutorial for an overview: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/viewing_and_clipping.htm)

Feel free to use any of the code below as a starting point (you have an intersect function and some useful classes). Implements Sutherland and Hodgman.

```
class Point2(object):
    """Structure for a 2D point"""
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __copy__(self):
        return self.__class__(self.x, self.y)
    copy = __copy__
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point2(%d, %d)' % (self.x, self.y)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return (self.x, self.y)[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        l = [self.x, self.y]
        l[key] = value
        self.x, self.y = l
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Point2):
            return self.x == other.x and \
                   self.y == other.y
        else:
            assert hasattr(other, '__len__') and len(other) == 2
            return self.x == other[0] and \
                   self.y == other[1]
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.x != 0 or self.y != 0
    def __len__(self):
        return 2


class Line2(object):
    """Structure for a 2D line"""
    def __init__(self,pt1,pt2):
        self.pt1,self.pt2=pt1,pt2
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Line2(%s, %s)' % (self.pt1, self.pt2)

class Polygon2(object):
    def __init__(self,points):
        self.points = points
    def __repr__(self):
        return '[\n %s\n]' % '\n '.join([str(i) for i in self.points])
    def lines(self):
        lines = []
        e = self.points[-1].copy()
        for p in self.points:
            lines.append(Line2(e,p))
            e = p.copy()
        return lines
        #return [Line2(a,b) for a,b in zip(self.points,self.points[1:]+[self.points[0]])]
    def __copy__(self):
        return self.__class__(list(self.points))
    copy = __copy__


class Renderer(object):
    """Rendering algorithm implementations"""
    def __init__(self,world,img,color=1):
        self.world,self.img,self.color=world,img,color
    def transform(self,s,r,m,n):
        """Homogeneous transformation operations"""
        for i in self.world.points():
            j = Matrix3.new_translate(m, n)*Matrix3.new_rotate(r)*Matrix3.new_scale(s)*i
            i.x,i.y = j.x,j.y
    def clip(self,a,b,c,d):
        """Clipping for the world window defined by a,b,c,d"""
        self.clip_lines(a, b, c, d)
        self.clip_polygons(a, b, c, d)
    def shift(self,a,b,c,d):
        """Shift the world window"""
        for i in self.world.points():
            i.x -= a
            i.y -= b
    def clip_lines(self,a,b,c,d):
        """Clipping for lines (i.e. open polygons)"""
        clipped = []
        for i in self.world.lines:
            clipped += [self.clip_lines_cohen_sutherland(i.pt1, i.pt2, a, b, c, d)]
        self.world.lines = [i for i in clipped if i]
    def clip_polygons(self,a,b,c,d):
        """Clipping for polygons"""
        polygons = []
        for polygon in self.world.polygons:
            new_polygon = self.clip_polygon_sutherland_hodgman(polygon, a, b, c, d)
            polygons.append(new_polygon)
        self.world.polygons = polygons
    def clip_polygon_sutherland_hodgman(self,polygon,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax):
        edges = [Line2(Point2(xmax,ymax),Point2(xmin,ymax)), #top
                 Line2(Point2(xmin,ymax),Point2(xmin,ymin)), #left
                 Line2(Point2(xmin,ymin),Point2(xmax,ymin)), #bottom
                 Line2(Point2(xmax,ymin),Point2(xmax,ymax)), #right
                 ]
        def is_inside(pt,line):
            # uses the determinant of the vectors (AB,AQ), Q(X,Y) is the query
            # left is inside
            det = (line.pt2.x-line.pt1.x)*(pt.y-line.pt1.y) - (line.pt2.y-line.pt1.y)*(pt.x-line.pt1.x)
            return det>=0
        def intersect(pt0,pt1,line):
            x1,x2,x3,x4 = pt0.x,pt1.x,line.pt1.x,line.pt2.x
            y1,y2,y3,y4 = pt0.y,pt1.y,line.pt1.y,line.pt2.y
            x = ((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4)) / ((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
            y = ((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4)) / ((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
            return Point2(int(x),int(y))
        polygon_new = polygon.copy()
        for edge in edges:
            polygon_copy = polygon_new.copy()
            polygon_new = Polygon2([])
            s = polygon_copy.points[-1]
            for p in polygon_copy.points:
                if is_inside(s,edge) and is_inside(p,edge):
                    polygon_new.points.append(p)
                elif is_inside(s,edge) and not is_inside(p,edge):
                    polygon_new.points.append(intersect(s,p,edge))
                elif not is_inside(s,edge) and not is_inside(p,edge):
                    pass
                else:
                    polygon_new.points.append(intersect(s,p,edge))
                    polygon_new.points.append(p)
                s = p
        return polygon_new
    def clip_lines_cohen_sutherland(self,pt0,pt1,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax):
        """Cohen-Sutherland clipping algorithm for line pt0 to pt1 and clip rectangle with diagonal from (xmin,ymin) to (xmax,ymax)."""
        TOP = 1
        BOTTOM = 2
        RIGHT = 4
        LEFT = 8
        def ComputeOutCode(pt):
            code = 0
            if pt.y > ymax: code += TOP
            elif pt.y < ymin: code += BOTTOM
            if pt.x > xmax: code += RIGHT
            elif pt.x < xmin: code += LEFT
            return code
        accept = False
        outcode0, outcode1 = ComputeOutCode(pt0), ComputeOutCode(pt1)
        while True:
            if outcode0==outcode1==0:
                accept=True
                break
            elif outcode0&outcode1:
                accept=False
                break
            else:
                #Failed both tests, so calculate the line segment to clip from an outside point to an intersection with clip edge.
                outcodeOut = outcode0 if not outcode0 == 0 else outcode1
                if TOP & outcodeOut:
                    x = pt0.x + (pt1.x - pt0.x) * (ymax - pt0.y) / (pt1.y - pt0.y)
                    y = ymax
                elif BOTTOM & outcodeOut:
                    x = pt0.x + (pt1.x - pt0.x) * (ymin - pt0.y) / (pt1.y - pt0.y)
                    y = ymin
                elif RIGHT & outcodeOut:
                    y = pt0.y + (pt1.y - pt0.y) * (xmax - pt0.x) / (pt1.x - pt0.x);
                    x = xmax;
                elif LEFT & outcodeOut:
                    y = pt0.y + (pt1.y - pt0.y) * (xmin - pt0.x) / (pt1.x - pt0.x);
                    x = xmin;
                if outcodeOut == outcode0:
                    pt0 = Point2(x,y)
                    outcode0 = ComputeOutCode(pt0)
                else:
                    pt1 = Point2(x,y)
                    outcode1 = ComputeOutCode(pt1);
        if accept:
            return Line2(pt0,pt1)
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Well, the segments are not in order, and not from a connected line. For the 'inside/outside' thing, yes the black polyline can be closed and considered as a polygon.

Comment: In the Cyrus and Beck algorithm, the difficulty, by having a polygon instead  of a rectangular clipping window, would be to find the orientation of the `Ni` vectors, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Lovy, and thats why you need a notion of inside and outside.

Comment: @Lovy and in response to your commend to the answer by Davy, as I mentioned in my reply, try to sort the segments that make your polygon BEFORE clipping (should be trivial, just look for pairs of segments where the beginning of one matches the ending of the other). After clipping just go through the same list and if the beginning/ending pair doesn't match, you know you need to add a new segment there. I will edit my answer and add example code implementing the Sutherland and Hodgman algorithm for a homework of mine, but it will give you a bunch of useful stuff to start with.

Comment: @Josep Valls, your updated answer seems to be much more effective, mine doesn't account for the blue shape crossing the black lines multiple times, but if you regard the black lines as a polygon with this inside-outside setup, you can bypass that. Great answer, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you'll need to do is find a line from the center of the blue object to the line segment in question. If that new line from the center to the segment AB or BC hits a black line on its way to the blue line segment, then that segment is outside and is trimmed. You would want to check this at a point between A and B or between B and C, so that you don't hit the intersection point.

As for the python aspect, I would recommend defining a line object class with some midpoint attributes and a shape class that's made up of lines with a center attribute, (Actually come to think of it, then a line would count as a shape so you could make line a child class of the shape class and preserve code), that way you can make methods that compare two lines as part of each object.

```
line_a = Line((4,2),(6,9))
line_b = Line((8,1),(2,10))
line_a.intersects(line.b) #Could return Boolean, or the point of intersection
```

In my mind that just feels like a really comfortable way to go about this problem since it lets you keep track of what everything's doing.

Comment: Thank you I think this could operate well! any ideas for step 2 ?